# image rectification from calibrated cameras using matlab

Tags: matlab, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst, stereo-3d

I have a set of multiple cameras for which I did a calibration procedure using this code: http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~svoboda/SelfCal/
and I found for each camera the intrinsic parameteres in 3x3 K matrix, rotation matrix R and translation vector t.
I now want to rectify the images from all the cameras.
Can anyone explain to me how to do that in matlab? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually rectification itself is a very simple process. You can use these formulas which involves very simple matrix multiplication.

`P1 = K1*[R1|T1] ; P2 = K2*[R2|T2] ; 
C1 = K1 *R1(inverse)* K1*T1 ; C2 =K2 * R2(inverse) * K2 * T2
V1 = C1 –C2 ; V2 =( last row of R1 )T X v1 (cross product); V3 = V1 X V2 (cross product)
R = [V1(transpose)  /norm(V1)
     V2(transpose) /norm(V2) 
     V3(transpose)/norm(V3) ]`

These equations are from the following paper:
http://david.fofi.free.fr/IMG/pdf/Fusiello_2000.pdf

They also have a MATLAB code available which you can use directly. Please check the paper.

I hope this helps.